# My Navigation bar is not being hidden,why?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

Very silly question but i have messed up on it.

My question is, i have two controller. first controller has an `UITableview` without navigation bar now when i will select the cell it will go to its corresponding controller which has navigation bar.Now when i will return back to first controller navigation bar should not display it should be hidden. How can i solve the problem.it is being bore to me.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

till now i have used it but it is not working.

please give me solution.

Thanks In advance

**EDIT**: first view controller----> In viewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear i have used `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];` In viewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear of second view controller i have used `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];`

**EDIT2:

**First view controller -->**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
  [super viewDidLoad];  
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

and in view will appear...

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 

  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

**Second controller -->**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

In view will appear --->

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 

     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

**EDIT** **ANSWER**

I have just used

```
[self.navigationController viewWillAppear:YES];
```

in viewDidLoad of first and second controller.

Comment: where are you calling the above method? also try to take help of any boolean variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to write `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];` in first controller's `viewWillAppear`  method.

Also try : `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];`

Comment: I have used you code but problem is when first controller load then nav bar become hide and next controller normally get his nav bar but when i return back to first controller then it shows me nav bar but first controller should not show nav bar.

Comment: same problem man...first nav bar hidden after return back nav bar not hidden.

Comment: write [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; in second view's back method too

Comment: make sure viewWillAppear is called

Comment: i agree with maulik, put a breakpoint over there and check it.

Comment: Another interesting thing is i do not face this problem in ios 5 simulator but in device i face this problem.and your question result is view will appear is calling not only for simulator but also in device.

Comment: you are just awesome man.....view will appear was not calling thats why i have called viewWillAppear from vc. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5431-viewwillappear-not-getting-called.html

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
}
```

or please try this

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;
```

Comment: Please try this ' [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
'

Comment: or try this -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];

 [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
  
}